# How server-socket with more than one backlog works?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, serversocket

I'm new to socket programming, I have problem in understanding serversocket.
assume we create a serversocket like this:

```
loadbalancerSocket = new ServerSocket(port, 20);
connection = loadbalancerSocket.accept();
```

and then after some stuff, write something in its buffer:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));
                writer.write("Hello!");
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
```

My question is : How the connection understand which client should get the response of server? our backlog is 20 , and 20 client can connect to the server socket at the same time(As I understood).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example the first connected client gets the response. The backlog parameter does not mean number of clients that can connect in parallel. It is the maximum number of clients waiting for accepting connection.

The `ServerSocket` is not connected to any particular client. The connected socket is the socket returned from `accept()`. If you want to handle multiple clients in parallel you have to call `accept()` multiple times and handle connections separately. You can create a special thread for each connection for example.

`accept()` is typically called in a loop and the newly created connected socket returned from `accept()` is typically passed to a handler that is responsible for particular client.